# width of email field on contribution form

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page

Using a WordPress installation. Initially the contribution form shows an amount field and an email field. Is there a way to make the email field wider. Currently both are the same width. Inspecting the page it appears that both fields use the same style attribute. I would like the email field to be about twice the width of the contribution field.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way to customize styling is by putting your custom CSS inside the css/extras.css file. But I'm not sure which page you mean. The front-end contribution page has different sizes (https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/contribution-page/) and the back-end New Contribution form doesn't have email on it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was not aware of the demo page. I cannot tell from the contribution page configuration what causes the email address field to be displayed. https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fcontribute%2Fsettings&reset=1&action=update&id=1

Comment: Are you able to edit your question to include a screenshot of what the contribution page looks like?

Comment: At Demerit request I tried to edit the question to include a screenshot, but all I as able to do was edit the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I meant a screenshot of your page on your site, not a screenshot of the public demo site.

Comment: I wasn't asking about my site, I am asking about the demo site.How does it know to have an email field.